# SQL MAX() function is very slow, is there a better method?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, max, min

I have a SQL database and ASP.NET web application and most of my queries involve the SQL max function.

For example, the below query takes between approx. 36 seconds to execute (when using the profiler) on both the ASP.NET website and the SSMS.

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) - 
       MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) AS ACTUALHOURSRUN 
FROM REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS 
WHERE ID_LOCATION = @ID_LOCATION AND 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,102) 
       BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

The table in question has approx. 5,000,000 records and 45 columns.

What is the best/fastest/most efficient way of executing the query to reduce the execution time?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First of all: do you have an index on `ID_Location`? Also: can you somehow avoid having all those conversions? Especially the one in the `WHERE` clause will be killing any performance you might have.....

Comment: What are the types of `Runhrs` and `Runho`?

Comment: And what makes you think that the `MAX` function is the part that is slow?. For the look of it, I would say that `CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,102) BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE` is slowing your query, since it can't use an index (even if you have one on the column `TIME_STAMP`) because you are using a function. What happens if you just do `SELECT *`with those filters?, how long does it takes?

Comment: Perhaps do your `CONVERT` outside the `MAX` and `MIN` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you need to do:

- **Make sure that the columns that you search are indexed** - You need an index on `ID_LOCATION` and `TIME_STAMP` (if you have other queries that query by date across locations or by locations across dates, you may consider defining separate indexes; otherwise, a single combined index will work).
- **Stop converting the timestamp to a string** - use the native data type for `@STARTDATE` and `@ENDDATE` in your query, or replace the condition with `TIME_STAMP between CONVERT(datetime,@STARTDATE) and CONVERT(datetime,@ENDDATE)`

These two changes should make your query faster, especially the second one: currently, `CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,102)` forces the query optimizer into a full scan on everything that matches your location, or even a full table scan if there is no index on `ID_LOCATION`. An indexed search should bring the number of records down to acceptable levels.

The final item to take on is `CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs, Runho))`: if the query speed after the first two modifications remains insufficient, change `MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho)))` to `CONVERT(FLOAT, MAX(ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho)))`, and do the same change for the `MIN`. This may or may not work, depending on the types of `Runhrs` and `Runho`.

Comment: Why separate indices? A single index on ID_LOCATION and TIME_STAMP would suffice. The ordering of the columns on the index *is* something to consider and depends on overall query patterns in the system

Comment: @AdaTheDev You are right, a single index on two columns may be sufficient for this query.

Answer (score 2):

An index on ID_LOCATION and TIME_STAMP would be a good candidate.

However, as you are converting the TIME_STAMP field to a VARCHAR, this will prevent it from being able to use the index. Instead, rework the query to remove the need to do the CONVERT and instead work with DATETIME values.

e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) - MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) AS ACTUALHOURSRUN 
FROM REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS 
WHERE ID_LOCATION = @ID_LOCATION AND TIME_STAMP >= @STARTDATE AND TIME_STAMP < @ENDDATE
```

Ensure @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE are DATETIME parameters also (I'm assuming this is the datatype of the TIME_STAMP column)

I'd also question what datatypes are the Runhrs/Runho columns? If not stored as FLOAT/DECIMAL already, then could they not be as that would appear to be the most suitable datatype?

Answer (score 0):

First, store Rhnhrs as a numeric type.  Then you don't need to do the conversion.

Second, you'll make this faster by creating an index on `hl_logs(id_location, time_stamp)`.  You could also throw `Runhrs` and `Runho` as well.  With an index on all four columns (in that order), the query will not even need to go to the original data.

To use the index, you need to change the `where` statement to something like:

```
 time_stamp bewteen @startTimeStamp and @EndTimeStamp
```

The SQL engine won't use the index if the variable is the argument to a function.

The resulting query should look more like:

```
select max(coalesce(runhrs, runho)) - min(coalesce(runhrs, runho) as Actual
from REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS 
WHERE ID_LOCATION = @ID_LOCATION AND 
      TIME_STAMP BETWEEN cast(@STARTDATE as datetime) AND cast(@ENDDATE as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, MAX(Runhrs)), CONVERT(FLOAT, MAX(Runho),
       CONVERT(FLOAT, MIN(Runhrs)), CONVERT(FLOAT, MIN(Runho)
FROM REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS 
WHERE ID_LOCATION = @ID_LOCATION
  AND TIME_STAMP BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Do the subtraction yourself in the code which call the SQL.  (That is the .net code.)

You should have an index on ID_LOCATION, TIME_STAMP, Runhrs, Runho.  One index with all four fields.  Maybe two indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS ON ID_LOCATION, TIME_STAMP, Runhrs
CREATE INDEX REPORTINGSYSTEM.DBO.HL_LOGS ON ID_LOCATION, TIME_STAMP, Runho
```

Comment: All this can be done without changing the datatype in the database.  You should change the datatype of STARTDATE and ENDDATE.  More performance gains may be possible by changing the datatypes in the database as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,102)
```

This is NOT the way to do it - it will cause slowness. Do NOT apply unnecessary functions to the DATA - it robs the optimizer of any chance to use indexes on this field. Do it the other way around, convert the `@STARTDATE` + `@ENDDATE` into the **same data type as the field**. (or, think of it this way you are doing ~ 5,000,000 conversions so that you can compare to 2 variables)

```
[time_stamp] BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Please understand this actually means:

```
[time_stamp] > = @STARTDATE AND [time_stamp] <= @ENDDATE
```

i.e. BOTH "boundary" datetimes are INCLUDED, usually it's easier and more accurate to avoid between's inclusive nature and spell it out like this:

```
[time_stamp] > = @STARTDATE AND [time_stamp] < @ENDDATE (with @enddate
being "next day at 00:00:00:000)

MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) -
MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) AS ACTUALHOURSRUN
```

wow, This is a lot of function calls! It's not pure `MAX()/MIN()` that's at issue here.

Suggest you simply look for `Max(Runhrs)` etc as previously mentioned, THEN do the subtractions.